# How to deal with giant lists/ Matrices in python? ( not chunkable)

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I have a python code which generates a list. The final outcome is a giant list (matrix) which causes memory error. This lists is not chunckabel and it completes as it goes till it hits the last column.

Following code works for up to N=15 in my PC.
I have Python 64 bit.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
#Initial SOC
iSOC=float(50)
#Target SOC
tSOC=float(60)
step1=3.75

def myFunction(base, plus):
#Initialize result array
    result = []
#For Each tuple in entry
    for bas in base:
    #Get Last Element
        lastElem = bas[-1:][0]
    #For Each element to add
        for x in plus:
        # Append a tuple composed of base + sum(lastElement & element to 
        #add)
            result.append(bas + ( (lastElem+x),) )
# Return result
    return result
N=6

df = [(iSOC,)]
for i in range(N):
    add = [step1,0,-step1]
    df=myFunction(df, [step1,0,-step1])

df1=pd.DataFrame(df)
df1
```

For N>15, it gives memory error. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what's the error when N>15, is memory overflow? post it out, please.

Comment: Do you need to go higher on `N`?  Memory errors do occur, either because a particular array is too large, or you have accumulated too many large arrays.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? At `N = 15`, the resulting dataframe has 14.3M rows and 16 columns of `float64`. That many floats alone occupy 1.7GB so memory problem is very possible

Comment: Hi, where exactly are you using pandas there? Btw. had a very hard time figuring out what you are looping over in `for bas in base` because you named your python-list `df` ;-)

Comment: So basically you are running out of memory, because you create 3^N entries in your list, which is 14,348,907 for N=15 (containing tuples each). No big surprise you're getting a memory error, is it? You should try chunking, or better, try to figure out how you can rewrite your logic, so it can generate the rows without "looking back" to previous records. This should be possible.

Comment: If you just want to give it a try without changing the logic to a big extent, you could try using numpy arrays and safe the overhead of pointers to objects. I guess `np.ndarray((3**N, N+1), dtype='float32')` should give you the correctly shaped array.